# JavaScript syntax for defining parameters

Tags: javascript, magento, parameters, algolia

I have a javascript file provided to me by a third party extension for search functionality on my magento store.

The third party has told me to define the parameter 'removeWordsIfNoResults' with value 'firstWords'.

I found this line in the js file:

this.removeWordsIfNoResults = params.removeWordsIfNoResults;

However, I'm not sure how to set this to be 'firstWords'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Who is `params`? can you provide some relevant code regarding the plugin?

Comment: I've taken a guess with my answer. You should _really_ include a proper snippet of the code you're working with. It's very hard to figure out what you're exactly talking about from _a single line of code._ Please read: [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The magento extension is called Algolia.  Here is a link to their support on this topic: https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#full-text-search-parameters

Comment: The documentation seems pretty darn clear. I've updated my answer, though. It's probably a pretty good idea to actually study JavaScript before you try all kinds of fancy libraries. This is very basic OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript), it's pretty much as I guessed, just not a constructor.

Inspect this example snippet from the documentation:

```
// simple query
index.search('jim', searchCallback);

// with parameters
index.search(
  'jim', {
    hitsPerPage: 5, facets: '*'
  },
  searchCallback
);

function searchCallback(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }

  content.hits.forEach(function(hit) {
    console.log(hit);
  });
}
```

Note that the second `.search` takes an `object` (`{}`) filled with values as its second argument, and the callback moves to the third argument position.

This is the object where you define your paramaters.

```
index.search(
  'jim', {
    removeWordsIfNoResults: 'firstWords'
  },
  searchCallback
);
```

**Original Answer:**

Sounds like you're working with some kind of a constructor, which wants a settings-like `object` passed to it.

Take a look at the MDN's [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for an overview on how objects can be created, passed around, accessed, and manipulated in JavaScript.

Here's an example of passing a configuration style object to a function - in this case a constructor function.

```js
function MyObject (config) {
  this.someKeyValue = config.someKeyValue;
}


var myObject = new MyObject({ someKeyValue: 'Some String' });

console.log(myObject.someKeyValue);
```